# Has anyone analysed the invented languages in the Earthsea books?

Tags: conlang-creation, vocabulary

Ursula K Le Guin's Earthsea stories contain vocabulary and utterances from three invented languages. The first step to fleshing these out into fully developed conlangs would be to list all the examples from the books and make some notes on any regularities or inconsistencies. Has anyone done this and put it up online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some information on one of them, *[Hardic](https://earthsea.fandom.com/wiki/Hardic)*, and [a fragmentary word list](http://www.tavia.co.uk/earthsea/dictionary.asp).

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept if no one else provides more stuff.